# AngularJS render taking long time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a particular page in my web app that is taking a really long time to load. After looking at the performance tab in the angularJS tool (inside chrome developer tools), it shows the functions that are killing performance. It looks a lot like this:

```
render | 24.0% | 1953ms
ngRepeatWatch | 20.4%| 1659ms
myFunction | 5.21% | 423ms
myOtherFunction | 5.05% | 412ms
parentValueWatch | 4.86% | 395ms
ngModelWatch | 4.09% | 332ms
```

This particular page is pretty watch intensive. Does that affect the time it takes to render? How can I improve the render time?

Comment: observe less things, but without code we can't tell much

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: so the watches directly affect the render?

Comment: the data set isnt HUGE, they are questions, almost like a form. there are about 100 questions.

Comment: Does each question have associated answers?

Comment: Yes, each question has associated answers. Some are prepopulated and some are not. All are editable by the viewer. Questions are dependent on each other which is why they have to be watched. If an answer is changed, we have to check to see if we need to automatically change others. Hence the watches.

Comment: If you cant reduce the number of the $watch expressions, or make them faster (every watch runs at every $digest calls twice) decrease the number of the items. Load the model, but display 10 form the 100 items at a time. Paginate or display more as the user scrolls, a get rid of the items on the top.
And don't do it with a filter on the ng-repeat do it with two arrays. One for the ng-repeat, and one for the data store.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/) to decrease the numbre of watchers, that will increase highly the page performance, especially when there is a huge amount of items to render